# selecting data from two tables,mysql

Tags: mysql

My database is having two tables customer and transaction.

customer table is having 8 columns,transaction table is having 4 columns,

customer table primary key is id,and in transaction table there is no primary key,per customer in transaction table there exists more than one record.

I need to select 4 columns from customer ,3 columns from transaction.

here is query:

```
query ='SELECT c.customer_id AS "Customer ID",
               c.father_name AS "Father Name",
               c.address AS Address,
               c.phone_number AS "Phone Number",
               c.mobile_number AS "Mobile Number",
               c.id_proof AS "ID Proof",
               c.area AS "Area",
               c.ip_address AS "IP Address",
               c.mac_address AS "MAC Address",
               c.package_type AS "Package Type",
               c.name AS Name,
               c.activation_date AS "Activation Date",
               c.status AS "Status",
               c.installation_cost AS "Installation Cost",
               c.totalamount_paid AS "Total Amount Paid",
               c.monthly_amount AS "Monthly Amount",
               c.lastpaid_date AS "Last Paid Date",
               c.lastpaid_amount AS "Last Paid Amount",
               c.nextpay_date AS "Next Pay Date",
               c.totaldue_amount AS "Total Due Amount",
               t.agent_id AS "Agent ID",
               t.token_number AS "Token Number",
               t.machine_id AS "Machine ID"
          FROM customer c INNER JOIN transaction t ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
        WHERE DATE(t.paid_date)BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "'AND '" + toDate + "' ";
```

But here the problem is:

How many times the record exists in transaction table,those times its giving records , But i need only once.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Would **LIMIT 1** fit your needs?

Comment: where can i kept in query

Comment: Why not use `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 1):

```
... GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

You'd most likely want to **SUM** some of the columns or use other aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your query logic. There are three columns that you are selecting from `transaction` table. Now, for one single customer, there can be multiple transactions. If you are selecting `t.agent_id`, `t.token_number` and `t.machine_id`, this will give you these values for every transaction made by the customer.

If your business logic permits this, remove these three columns from the `select` list and use an `EXISTS` clause instead of an `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
query ='SELECT c.customer_id AS "Customer ID",
               c.father_name AS "Father Name",
               c.address AS Address,
               c.phone_number AS "Phone Number",
               c.mobile_number AS "Mobile Number",
               c.id_proof AS "ID Proof",
               c.area AS "Area",
               c.ip_address AS "IP Address",
               c.mac_address AS "MAC Address",
               c.package_type AS "Package Type",
               c.name AS Name,
               c.activation_date AS "Activation Date",
               c.status AS "Status",
               c.installation_cost AS "Installation Cost",
               c.totalamount_paid AS "Total Amount Paid",
               c.monthly_amount AS "Monthly Amount",
               c.lastpaid_date AS "Last Paid Date",
               c.lastpaid_amount AS "Last Paid Amount",
               c.nextpay_date AS "Next Pay Date",
               c.totaldue_amount AS "Total Due Amount" /*,
               t.agent_id AS "Agent ID",
               t.token_number AS "Token Number",
               t.machine_id AS "Machine ID" -- */
          FROM customer c 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM transaction t
                       WHERE c.customer_id = t.customer_id
                         AND DATE(t.paid_date)BETWEEN '"
                                                        + fromDate
                                                        + "'AND '"
                                                        + toDate + "' "
```

Now, if your business does need those three values, you can simply use a `SELECT DISTINCT` and stop worrying about duplicate values.

Comment: where to use DISTINCT in query

Comment: Simple - ext to `SELECT`, like `query ='SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_id ...`. You look new to SQL. I suggest you do some more homework. Go to the SQL tutorials of w3schools.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
query = " ... ... ... GROUP BY c.customer_id";
```

Comment: not this , it's giving only first record,i want per customer only one record

Comment: am developing .net application,Shall i write the query as:after that above query with group by.if (reportsmachine.Text != "")
                            {
                                query = query + " AND " + "t.machine_id=" + "'" + reportsmachine.Text + "' ";
                            }
                            if (reportscustomer.Text != "")
                            {
                                query = query + " AND " + "t.customer_id=" + "'" + reportscustomer.Text + "' ";}there reportscustomer and reportsmachine are textboxes.

Comment: @SahilMittal - well, it seems I gave that answer 7 minutes before you and you've just edited yours to resemble mine. So, if it is correct it is my answer to be accepted. Heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

`query ='SELECT c.customer_id AS "Customer ID",
               c.father_name AS "Father Name",
               c.address AS Address,
               c.phone_number AS "Phone Number",
               c.mobile_number AS "Mobile Number",
               c.id_proof AS "ID Proof",
               c.area AS "Area",
               c.ip_address AS "IP Address",
               c.mac_address AS "MAC Address",
               c.package_type AS "Package Type",
               c.name AS Name,
               c.activation_date AS "Activation Date",
               c.status AS "Status",
               c.installation_cost AS "Installation Cost",
               c.totalamount_paid AS "Total Amount Paid",
               c.monthly_amount AS "Monthly Amount",
               c.lastpaid_date AS "Last Paid Date",
               c.lastpaid_amount AS "Last Paid Amount",
               c.nextpay_date AS "Next Pay Date",
               c.totaldue_amount AS "Total Due Amount",
               t.agent_id AS "Agent ID",
               t.token_number AS "Token Number",
               t.machine_id AS "Machine ID"
        FROM customer c INNER JOIN transaction t ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
        WHERE DATE(t.paid_date)BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "'AND '" + toDate + "' "
        GROUP BY c.customer_id;`